# Duvida Java Server Faces

Tags: java, jsf

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em JSF, tenho uma classe Bean que possui um método.
Nesse método tenho uma variável do tipo String e conforme o método vai executando, a variável vai atualizando valores.

Gostaria de saber se é possível em tempo de execução atualizar um componente
 textArea em que essa variável está sendo apresentada?

```
<p:inputTextarea id="display" rows="15" cols="50" 
    value="#{fluxoPeriodo.displayMessage}"/>
```

Lembrando que a atualização só ocorre quando o método finaliza a execução

[image: Dialog para descrição de processos]

A cada vez que passar por um método, gostaria que ele fosse preenchendo as informações.

```
    int flag = 0;

    flag = isNum2();
    mess(flag);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add("idformdialog:display");

    try{ Thread.sleep(8000); 
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {} 

    flag = isNum3();
    mess(flag);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add("idformdialog:display");
```

Tenho uma variável flag do tipo inteiro que recebe o valor de **isNum()**, quando passar por esse método recebe um valor inteiro, e logo passa para o método **mess(flag)**. Dependendo do valor da flag, o método deverá retornar uma mensagem, mas o problema é que ele só está mostrando as mensagens quando o método em que os métodos estão sendo executados termina sua execução.

```
<p:commandButton value="Buscar" id="pesquisa"
        class="ui-button-custom ui-button-busca"
        action="#{fluxoPeriodo.teste}" process="@form"
        update="@form" 
        onclick="PF('statusDialog').show();">                               
</p:commandButton>
```

Acima o botão onde chamo o método teste, o qual métodos acima estão sendo processados.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Você quer atualizar o campo ao decorrer da execução do método?

Comment: Exato, o **inputTextArea** deve receber as informações durante o processo, quero criar algo assim.

Comment: A atualização do campo pelo managed bean funcionou? Não entendi exatamente qual o problema agora

Comment: Ainda não consegui colocar a funcionar.

Comment: O problema é o seguinte, após passar pelo método deveria atualizar um valor na minha **paginá.xhtml**, mas ele só está atualizando quando o método pelo qual eu chamo pelo **commandButton** finaliza execução. Nessa método da ação tem outros métodos sendo executados, após cada um deles gostaria que atualizasse uma mensagem.

Answer (score 1):

Com Primefaces 6.2 você pode utilizar o seguinte comando dentro do seu Managed Bean:

```
PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("form:id:meu:campo");
```

No caso do JSF puro, você deve adicionar o id do seu campo no contexto de renderização parcial da view:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add("form:id:meu:campo");
```

Ao decorrer do seu método você pode ir atualizando o campo conforme as steps do seu processo são concluídas.